# My jekyll blog won't render properly when hosted on Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm on a Windows 10 machine, a few days ago I downloaded a Jekyll theme to use as my personal portfolio site, after making a branch called gh-pages and pushing it to that branch it is not rendering properly, here is the URL: https://nezmustafa123.github.io/blog/

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: wow marcanuy it worked I was struggling with this for a long time thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem on your site URL configuration, instead of loading the CSS from https://nezmustafa123.github.io/blog/assets/css/main.css it is looking for http://localhost:4000/assets/css/main.css.

In the configuration file `_config.yml` chenge the following key to your website domain:

```
url: http://localhost:4000
```

and add the baseurl: `baseurl: "blog"`.

Then adjust your head includes using `site.url` to use the `base_url` prefix in `_includes/head.html` or generate the absolute path including the url with `absolute_url`:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ "/assets/css/main.css" | relative_url }}">
```

> Relative URL
>
> Prepend the baseurl value to the input. Useful if your site is hosted
>   at a subpath rather than the root of the domain.
>
> Absolute URL
>
> Prepend the url and baseurl value to the input.